# Index out of range exception cannot find column

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Hello I have this problem in came upon when trying to do simple manual search in vb.net. It says System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find column 4.'
could anyone explain what this means i am quite new to coding and dont quite get what i could to do fix this. In the attached database i have only one table called customer with 4 columns custid, custfname, custlname and dob.
This is the code and the error occurs in the btnNext and Navigaterecords. The database was made in sqlite

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
```

Public Class Form1

```
Dim inc As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Integer

Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=dbRoomBookings.db"
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim mSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Customer"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mSQL, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "customer")
    dt = ds.Tables(0)

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("customer").Rows.Count
    con.Close()


    Dim msSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM customer;"
    dgvSearchResults.DataSource = display(msSQL, "customer")


End Sub


Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then
        inc = inc + 1
        txtCusId.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(0)
        txtFname.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(1)
        txtLname.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(2)
        cboDay.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3)
        cboMonth.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(4)
        cboYear.Text = ds.Tables("Customer").Rows(inc).Item(5)

    Else

        MsgBox("no more rows")
    End If

End Sub
Sub navigaterecords()
    txtCusId.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(0)
    txtFname.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    txtLname.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    cboDay.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3)
    cboMonth.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(4)
    cboYear.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(5)
    txtDbo.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3) & "/" & ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(4) & "/" & ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(5)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    If inc > 0 Then
        inc = inc - 1
        navigaterecords()
    Else

        MsgBox("no more rows")

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BtnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
    If inc <> 0 Then

        inc = 0

        navigaterecords()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BtnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then

        inc = MaxRows - 1

        navigaterecords()
    Else

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim newds As New DataSet
    Dim newdt As New DataTable

    If txtSearchFname.Text <> "" Then
        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE custfname LIKE'" & txtSearchFname.Text & "%'"

        Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sSQL, con)
        con.Open()
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(newds, "customer")
        newdt = newds.Tables(0)

        dgvSearchResults.DataSource = newdt
        con.Close()

    ElseIf txtSearchId.Text <> "" Then
        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE custid ='" & txtSearchId.Text & "'"

        Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sSQL, con)
        con.Open()
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(newds, "customer")
        newdt = newds.Tables(0)

        dgvSearchResults.DataSource = newdt
        con.Close()

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim con2 As New SQLiteConnection
    Dim da2 As New SQLiteDataAdapter
    Dim dsql, qsql As String
    Dim ds2 As New DataSet
    Dim dt2 As DataTable

    con2 = New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
    dsql = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE custid = " & txtSearchId.Text & ""
    qsql = "SELECT * FROM customer"
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(qsql, con2)

    con2.Open()

    da2.DeleteCommand = con2.CreateCommand
    da2.DeleteCommand.CommandText = dsql
    da2.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Row(s) Deleted !! ")

    Dim da3 As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
    da3.Fill(ds2, "customer")
    dt2 = ds2.Tables(0)

    dgvSearchResults.DataSource = dt2

    con2.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim con3 As New SQLiteConnection
    Dim da3 As New SQLiteDataAdapter

    con3 = New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)

    Dim usql As String = "UPDATE Customer SET custfname = '" & txtFname.Text & "'" & "WHERE custid =" & CInt(txtCusId.Text) & ""

    con3.Open()

    da3.UpdateCommand = con3.CreateCommand
    da3.UpdateCommand.CommandText = usql
    da3.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Row Updated")

End Sub

Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim isql As String = "INSERT INTO customer(custfname, custlname, dob) VALUES('" _
        & txtFname.Text & "','" & txtLname.Text & "','" & cboYear.Text _
        & "-" & cboMonth.Text & "-" & cboDay.Text & "');"

    Dim msql As String = "SELECT * FROM customer"

    add(isql)

    'refresh the Data Grid
    dgvSearchResults.DataSource = display(msql, "customer")


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: With `ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(4)` you are trying to access the 5th column of the table.

Comment: so do i need to change it to ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3)?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't try and access the columns by index, try by name in my opinion. You can always check if a column exist's by name. Another point is, if you change your query, now you have another place to check as well, the order could change. Also use parameters, specify their data types and length. Use `Using` statements to ensure that objects are properly disposed of when done.

Comment: Argh! Sql injection! **Always use parameters**

Comment: I shouldn't have to wade through your entire program and guess where your exception occurred. Tells us what line caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the specific documentation on IndexOutOfRangeException: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception

For visibility, the definition is:

> The exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to access an
> element of an array or collection with an index that is outside its
> bounds.

In your case, you are trying to get a value by passing the index of a column but the index you're passing is greater than the total number of columns.

Assuming that your table definition has the following columns: custfname, custlname, and dob, the following represents when the Exception would occur:

1. Get column 0, returns the value of *custfname*
2. Get column 1, returns the value of *custlname*
3. Get column 2, returns the value of *dob*
4. Get column 3, throws an IndexOutOfRangeException

The same thing would also happen if you tried to get a value at a negative index too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 4-column table which will have indexes from 0 to 3 only:

`custid` is column 0, `custfname` is column 1, `custfname` is column 2, and `dob` is column 3.

So any attempt to access `ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(4)` (and (5), etc) will yield an `Index out of range` exception.

But you seem to know that the table only has 4 columns; why are you then attempting to access columns that you know don't exist? I'm a bit confused by that. If you're trying to split DOB into day/month/year, you'll have to manipulate the `dob` value from the DOB composite column, Item(3).

Comment: Thank you for your help but could i ask how would i manipulate the dob value ?

Comment: @Offlin3 It depends on the format. If it's a string then use something like `dob.Split()` or `dob.Substring()`. Info on these is available everywhere. Watch out for any variations in length, delimiter, regional representation (m/d/y vs d/m/y), etc.

Comment: Thanks you very much!!

Comment: @Offlin3 No problem. Feel free to up-vote/mark as answer.

Comment: could you perhaps show me how to use the dob.split() to split my dob to 3 textboxes  cboDay.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3)
    cboMonth.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(4)
    cboYear.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(5)

Comment: @Offlin3 I think you probably should refer to the [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) and give it a try first.

Comment: @Offlin3 Don't ask a second question in comments. Post a new question with relevant code. Other users will not be able to find answers buried in comments.